# Determine type of active window

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a dialog class and a class derived from the dialog class. Now I want to know if the active modal is the base class or the sub class.

`CBaseDlg` and `CSubDlg`

Can I use something like this?

```
bool bIsSubclass;

CWnd* pWnd;
pWnd=((CMainFrame *)AfxGetMainWnd())->GetActiveWindow();
bIsSubclass = pWnd->IsKindOf();
```

or this?

```
bool bIsSubclass;

CWnd* pWnd;
CRuntimeClass* pRuntimeClass = pWnd->GetRuntimeClass();
bIsSubclass = pRuntimeClass->IsDerivedFrom(RUNTIME_CLASS());
```

If so, what do I pass into IsKindOf or Runtime_class?

Or is there any other way to determine the class?

Edit:

I've tried this but I get an error:

```
bIsSubclass = pWnd->IsKindOf(RUNTIME_CLASS(CSubDlg));
```

&

```
bIsSubclass = pRuntimeClass->IsDerivedFrom(RUNTIME_CLASS(CSubDlg));
```

[image]

Comment: The error indicates, that you have to include the header file of `CSubDlg`.

Comment: @MartinZabel The header file is included :/

Comment: Is the namespace right? Can you declare a variable like `CSubDlg *p` before.

Comment: Looks like there is something wrong with the include. When I had it above all includes it was recognized as a class in RUNTIME_CLASS() but I could not declare a variable. When I moved it down I could declare one but I get 155 random errors

Comment: Are the class and header files originally created by Visual Studio? Or maybe, do you copied one class/header file and missed to update the `#ifdef` protecting the multiple inclusion of a header.

Comment: I've created the files. But I have not added any `#ifdef` or `#ifndef`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95473/discussion-between-martin-zabel-and-johan-magnusson).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usage of `isKindOf` is described in the [MSDN Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/b7tsah76.aspx) (switch language if required).

Assuming that `CWnd` implements the required interfaces you just have to pass `RUNTIME_CLASS(CSubDlg)` as the argument to `isKindOf`, e.g.:

```
CWnd* pWnd = ((CMainFrame *)AfxGetMainWnd())->GetActiveWindow();
bool bIsSubclass = pWnd->IsKindOf(RUNTIME_CLASS(CSubDlg));
```

Answer (score 0):

To allow getting run-time class info for a given object, you'll have to use  `DECLARE_DYNAMIC`/`IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC` or `DECLARE_DYNCREATE`/`IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE` macros. So you'll get

1. the ability to access run-time information about an object's class,
   i.e. a `CRuntimeClass` type member and `GetRuntimeClass()` function.
2. the ability to dynamically create at run-time, i.e. `CreateObject()`
   member function.

Here is the recipe:

1. Specify `DECLARE_DYNCREATE(CSubDlg)` in your header file
2. Specify `IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE(CSubDlg, CDialog)` in your cpp file

After that you should be able to use the following syntax:

```
BOOL bIsSubclass = pWnd->IsKindOf(RUNTIME_CLASS(CSubDlg));
```